# ReactiveMongo|CosmosDb: How to connect to Cosmos Db using ReactiveMongo using URI

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

community. I am having a hard time connecting to Cosmos Db using Reactive Mongo client. I am able to connect to it using shell and NoSqlBooster client but failing using Reactive Mongo.

```
Authentication Mechanism |-------| Result
 **scram-sha1**                   Authentication failed, SaslFailed
 **mongocr**                      Authentication failed
```

**URI tried:**

```
mongodb://****:*****@******.documents.azure.com:10255/c360?ssl=true&authenticationMechanism=scram-sha1&sslAllowsInvalidCert=true
mongodb://****:*****@******.documents.azure.com:10255/c360?ssl=true
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Check the credential and `authenticationDatabase` ( http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/connect-database.html )

Comment: I tried that as well.

Comment: See http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.1x/documentation/tutorial/azure-cosmos.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to make it work using this configuration:

```
mongodb://****:*****@****.documents.azure.com:10255/c360?ssl=true&authenticationMechanism=mongocr&sslAllowsInvalidCert=true&authenticationDatabase=admin


?ssl=true
&authenticationMechanism=mongocr
&sslAllowsInvalidCert=true
&authenticationDatabase=admin
```

I tried this configuration group earlier as well, but, I guess I might have spilled something extra in username and password.

Comment: Requiring `authenticationMechanism=mongocr` means the DB is using old authentication, whereas MongoScram is recommanded since 3.0